# Running tail command inside a docker container is not working

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to tail a file inside a docker container.

Here's the code:

```
f = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F', "-n 0", "/var/log/auth.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p = select.poll()
    p.register(f.stdout)

while True:
    if p.poll(1):
        print(f.stdout.readline())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.4-alpine
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  tailssh:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: tail-ssh
    volumes:
      - /var/log:/var/log
      - ./logs:/logs
    env_file: .env
```

If I run `docker exec tail-ssh tail -F -n 0 /var/log/auth.log` the output was the expected but if the line I'm printing is always blank. Any idea?

Comment: Can you just `open()` the file and read it, rather than trying to launch a subprocess?

Comment: can you add the `docker compose` command you are using to start up your container? Also, can you alter your python code to always at least print something after each sleep?